# maven multi module project - jar size

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to maven (spring boot) project build and I am currently exploring the ways of implementing a solution using simple/micro services. I had created a new maven project in eclipse which had two main classes with common dependencies. Until yesterday, I was hoping to build two jars out of the main project which would contain a self sufficient pack of code within the jar. However this seemed very difficult due to the complexities of the pom and the loads of different/conflicting answers available on the internet. When I decided to move away from that idea (of using one project to build number of independent components), I was struck by the modules functionality. Then I created a new maven (parent) and two modules, defined the dependencies within the parent POM file. And did maven clean and install. This had resulted in two jars in each of the module target folders. Now I have the original (small) and other (bigger) jars under each of the modules.

The question I have is:
I am planning to deploy this to a server (say cloud) and I want to use the smallest possible size for jar files for obvious reasons. And this conflicts with the fact that spring boot is self sufficient (packed with all dependencies). so, is there an intelligent method of deploying jar files where a common jar is deployed along with module jars? Let us say dep.jar, mod1.jar and mod2.jar is all what I need from java classes point of view. dep.jar may be of size 15-20mb and mod1&2 of size 15kb approximately. this way it reduces a lot of memory consumption.

You may ask, why do I want to do this way. I am trying to split things up so that if I have to improve mod1, it will not affect mod2. Also, I believe this is the fundamental concept for micro-services. Over to the experts now.

Tagging SCDF here as this deployment will finally land on the scdf server.

I do see similar questions asked on this forum but I am confident their objectives are not the same as mine.